Scatter letter on screen and image appearing on hover debug
I am having trouble with debugging the scatter letters and my project link aspects. I can’t figure out why on media screen it’s not working, and now I have also made the contact links disappear on both.
I am new to programming and would appreciate support to help me learn!
Below is the link to my repo.
https://github.com/milanawood/portfolio
Thank you,
Milana
I have tried changing CSS and is and keep making sure they’re correctly working together but each time I fix one thing I seem to create another issue.

please post (minimal) relevant code in the question - a link to your github repo is pointless

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research.  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [<>] snippet editor HERE at SO

It is not clear what you are asking. You do know that there is no hover on a mobile? A long touch seems to show your images in debug mobile on Chrome

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Ok thank you for the feedback! I haven’t posted here before and I did not know the above as I am still learning.
